# MWFeedParser Attributes

Tags: iphone, xml, ios4, rss

Hi
i have this line of xml code:

```
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/7_1PfqGVSg0/0.jpg' height='240' width='320' time='00:01:34.500'/>
```

and i want to extract the url Attribute.
how can i do it?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing this xml than you can do it easily as follows :

In you `didStartElement` method of parsing delegate you have to use :

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) 
{
  NSString *yourUrl = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
}
```

`attributeDict` is last parameter coming in `didStartElement` method this holdes key value pair of attributes in particular tag.

Comment: can you show me where to edit in my project? http://www.mediafire.com/?z0sysbdx290s3de it should be in the MWFeedParser.m file but i dont know where...

Comment: In class MWFeedParser.m of MWFeedParser project, you will find - didStartElement:  method there you have to get the value of URL.

Comment: yes but how? can you edit and upload it so i will see? and tnx you!